# Android - replace findViewById with Butterknife

Tags: android, findviewbyid, butterknife

I have successfully replaced `findViewByIds` with Butterknife library. 
Unfortunately, one problem has occured:

```
final Button btnPopup = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup); //popupView.findViewById(...) problem!!!
```

How can I change this line of code in Butterknife: as `Butterknife.bind(this);` takes the whole activities `Views`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind your popupView to your main view using

```
View popupView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.yourPopup, null);
ButterKnife.bind(this,popupView);
```

Or you may want to bind it directly using

```
Button btnPopup = ButterKnife.findById(popupView, R.id.btn_popup);
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. Smoothly

Comment: Just take the second one. This inflates your popup view and finds the reference to your button. Your welcome ;)

Comment: Yes. I took 2nd.

Comment: Thank you, dont worry. Score is just a score, helping is valueable ;) But if you want to accept it since it helped you, feel free to accept it. Thanks for that.

Comment: I will accept it not because to give u more score, but rather to help other users to know that there is such solution

Comment: If you call `bind()` in a fragment, don't forget to call `unbind()` at `onDestroyView()` to avoid view leak when you detach the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there two thing which is added in dependency to use `ButterKnife` library:

Buil.gradle

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Then, after using `@BindView` above `onCreate` method inside the method write `ButterKnife(this, "any other unrelated views to this layout"`)

"any other unrelated views to this layout" can be another layout's contents such as **Popup window** or ....